# Sharepoint Open-Source/Own-server equivalent/alternative

Tags: untagged

I think sharepoint is great for coordinating tasks and tracking them, and the way users get emails automatically each time deadlines get closer and they then report about their advance and all that stuff. But for us this is unaffordable. I wonder about some Sharepoint Open-Source/Own-server (that can be installed in our server) equivalent/alternative

Answer (score 2):

Actually, [SharePoint 2010 Foundation](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/en-us/product/Related-Technologies/Pages/SharePoint-Foundation.aspx) is free.  It does require a 64-bit server and depending on the amount of files you want to store it might need a lot of disk space and RAM.  The pay versions are SharePoint Server Standard and Enterprise and can be compared on Microsoft's website at http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/en-us/buy/Pages/Editions-Comparison.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

Did you already look at Alfresco? It has a similar feature set to SharePoint. 
http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Download_Community_Edition

Answer (score 1):

I think the ECM [Alfresco](http://www.alfresco.com/) could did the trick... especially the [Alfresco Community Edition](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Download_and_Install_Alfresco).

Comment: I think it looks really good!

Comment: BTW, is it possible to migrate a google site to alfreso easily?

Comment: can I do project and task management with alfresco? I visited the website but found no relevant information

Answer (score 0):

Alfresco does not have workflow and does not support custom list based content types as SharePoint does. Workflow alone makes SharePoint worth looking at.

But you need to consider it does require Server 2008 CALs. You would also need some sort of version of SQL Server. SQL Server 2008 R2 Express is free but only supports 10 GB databases. So there are some drawbacks to consider.